# Implementing Admin menu in Codevision project with RFID-RC522 reader and ATMEGA164a, trouble in enrollment of key tags

Tags: rfid, atmega16, codevisionavr

I'm trying to make a project in Codevison, with ATMEGA164a, to be more specific, a contactless card reader with RFID-RC522. This project requires two interfaces, User-'U' and Admin-'A'. I started to implement the Admin menu, which allows to delete-'D', view-'V' and enroll-'E' a card and I have a problem when I have to enroll the key tag. When I'm trying to call the RFID's functions, especially those two: " mfrc522_init(); " and " byte = mfrc522_request(PICC_REQALL,str); ", but it doesn't do the right thing and it brings me back to the main menu. How can I fix it? Thank you.

```
**The enroll main code :**



else if(temp == 'E'|| temp == 'e'){ 
                lcd_clear(); 
                flag = 1; 
                spi_init(); 
                mfrc522_init();
                lcd_putsf("Enroll"); 
                byte = mfrc522_request(PICC_REQALL,str);
                 if(byte == CARD_FOUND){
                     byte = mfrc522_get_card_serial(str);
                 }                             
                while(flag){
                byte = mfrc522_request(PICC_REQALL,str);
                if(byte == CARD_FOUND){
                        temp2[0] = '\0';
                        for(byte=0;byte<5;byte++) {
                            itoa(str[byte],rez);
                            strcat(temp2,rez);
                        }   
                        flag = 0; 
                        
                } 
                else{
                        lcd_clear();
                        lcd_putsf("Erorr");
                        delay_ms(3000);
                        lcd_clear();
                    } 
             }   
                  
            if(!strcmp(card1,temp2)) lcd_putsf("Card 1 exists.");
            else if(!strcmp(card2,temp2)) lcd_putsf("Card 2 exists.");
            else if(!strcmp(card3,temp2)) lcd_putsf("Card 3 exists.");
            else if(card_empty_check(1)) {
                strcpy(card1,temp2);
                write_card(1);
                lcd_putsf("Card 1 saved.");
            }
            else if(card_empty_check(2)) {
                strcpy(card2,temp2);
                write_card(2);
                lcd_putsf("Card 2 saved.");
            }
            else if(card_empty_check(3)){
                strcpy(card3,temp2);
                write_card(3);
                lcd_putsf("Card 3 saved.");
            }else lcd_putsf("No space.");
            
            //delay_ms(1000);
                       
           } 

`




**The functions called:** 


char card1[11];
char card2[11];
char card3[11];
char empty[] = "0000000000";

int card1_empty = 0;
int card2_empty = 0;
int card3_empty = 0;

void write_card(int n){
    if(n == 1) eeprom_write_block((void*)&card1, (eeprom void*)0, 10);
    if(n == 2) eeprom_write_block((void*)&card2, (eeprom void*)10, 10);
    if(n == 3) eeprom_write_block((void*)&card3, (eeprom void*)20, 10);
}


int card_empty_check(int n) {
    if(n == 1) {
        if(!strcmp(card1,empty)) return 1;
    }
    if(n == 2) {
        if(!strcmp(card2,empty)) return 1;
    }
    if(n == 3) {
        if(!strcmp(card3,empty)) return 1;
    }
    
    return 0;
}
     


int full_card_empty_check() {
    for(i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
        if(!card_empty_check(i)) return 0;
    }
    
    return 1;
}

**mfrc522.c:**

#include "mfrc522.h"
#include "spi.h"
#include <mega164a.h>
#if 1
#include <alcd.h>
#endif


#define MFRC522_RST PORTB.0
#define MFRC522_SS PORTB.4

void mfrc522_init()
{
    uint8_t byte;
    mfrc522_reset();
    
    mfrc522_write(TModeReg, 0x8D);
    mfrc522_write(TPrescalerReg, 0x3E);
    mfrc522_write(TReloadReg_1, 30);   
    mfrc522_write(TReloadReg_2, 0);    
    mfrc522_write(TxASKReg, 0x40);    
    mfrc522_write(ModeReg, 0x3D);
    
    byte = mfrc522_read(TxControlReg);
    if(!(byte&0x03))
    {
        mfrc522_write(TxControlReg,byte|0x03);
    }   
    

}

void mfrc522_write(uint8_t reg, uint8_t data)
{
    ENABLE_CHIP();
    spi_transmit((reg<<1)&0x7E);
    spi_transmit(data);
    DISABLE_CHIP();
}

uint8_t mfrc522_read(uint8_t reg)
{
    uint8_t data;    
    ENABLE_CHIP();
    spi_transmit(((reg<<1)&0x7E)|0x80);
    data = spi_transmit(0x00);
    DISABLE_CHIP();
    return data;
}

void mfrc522_reset()
{
    mfrc522_write(CommandReg,SoftReset_CMD);
}

uint8_t    mfrc522_request(uint8_t req_mode, uint8_t * tag_type)
{
    uint8_t  status;  
    uint32_t backBits;//The received data bits

    mfrc522_write(BitFramingReg, 0x07);//TxLastBists = BitFramingReg[2..0]   
    
    tag_type[0] = req_mode;
    status = mfrc522_to_card(Transceive_CMD, tag_type, 1, tag_type, &backBits);

    if ((status != CARD_FOUND) || (backBits != 0x10))
    {    
        status = ERROR;
    }
   
    return status;    
    
    
}

uint8_t mfrc522_to_card(uint8_t cmd, uint8_t *send_data, uint8_t send_data_len, uint8_t *back_data, uint32_t *back_data_len)
{
    uint8_t status = ERROR;
    uint8_t irqEn = 0x00;
    uint8_t waitIRq = 0x00;
    uint8_t lastBits;
    uint8_t n;
    uint8_t  tmp;
    uint32_t i;

    switch (cmd)
    {
        case MFAuthent_CMD:        //Certification cards close
        {
            irqEn = 0x12;
            waitIRq = 0x10;
            break;
        }
        case Transceive_CMD:    //Transmit FIFO data
        {
            irqEn = 0x77;
            waitIRq = 0x30;
            break;
        }
        default:
            break;
    }
   
    //mfrc522_write(ComIEnReg, irqEn|0x80);    //Interrupt request
    n=mfrc522_read(ComIrqReg);
    mfrc522_write(ComIrqReg,n&(~0x80));//clear all interrupt bits
    n=mfrc522_read(FIFOLevelReg);
    mfrc522_write(FIFOLevelReg,n|0x80);//flush FIFO data
    
    mfrc522_write(CommandReg, Idle_CMD);    //NO action; Cancel the current cmd???

    //Writing data to the FIFO
    for (i=0; i<send_data_len; i++)
    {   
        mfrc522_write(FIFODataReg, send_data[i]);    
    }

    //Execute the cmd
    mfrc522_write(CommandReg, cmd);
    if (cmd == Transceive_CMD)
    {    
        n=mfrc522_read(BitFramingReg);
        mfrc522_write(BitFramingReg,n|0x80);  
    }   
    
    //Waiting to receive data to complete
    i = 2000;    //i according to the clock frequency adjustment, the operator M1 card maximum waiting time 25ms???
    do 
    {
        //CommIrqReg[7..0]
        //Set1 TxIRq RxIRq IdleIRq HiAlerIRq LoAlertIRq ErrIRq TimerIRq
        n = mfrc522_read(ComIrqReg);
        i--;
    }
    while ((i!=0) && !(n&0x01) && !(n&waitIRq));

    tmp=mfrc522_read(BitFramingReg);
    mfrc522_write(BitFramingReg,tmp&(~0x80));
    
    if (i != 0)
    {    
        if(!(mfrc522_read(ErrorReg) & 0x1B))    //BufferOvfl Collerr CRCErr ProtecolErr
        {
            status = CARD_FOUND;
            if (n & irqEn & 0x01)
            {   
                status = CARD_NOT_FOUND;            //??   
            }

            if (cmd == Transceive_CMD)
            {
                   n = mfrc522_read(FIFOLevelReg);
                  lastBits = mfrc522_read(ControlReg) & 0x07;
                if (lastBits)
                {   
                    *back_data_len = (n-1)*8 + lastBits;   
                }
                else
                {   
                    *back_data_len = n*8;   
                }

                if (n == 0)
                {   
                    n = 1;    
                }
                if (n > MAX_LEN)
                {   
                    n = MAX_LEN;   
                }
                
                //Reading the received data in FIFO
                for (i=0; i<n; i++)
                {   
                    back_data[i] = mfrc522_read(FIFODataReg);    
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {   
            status = ERROR;  
        }
        
    }
    
    //SetBitMask(ControlReg,0x80);           //timer stops
    //mfrc522_write(cmdReg, PCD_IDLE); 

    return status;
}


uint8_t mfrc522_get_card_serial(uint8_t * serial_out)
{
    uint8_t status;
    uint8_t i;
    uint8_t serNumCheck=0;
    uint32_t unLen;
    
    mfrc522_write(BitFramingReg, 0x00);        //TxLastBists = BitFramingReg[2..0]
 
    serial_out[0] = PICC_ANTICOLL;
    serial_out[1] = 0x20;
    status = mfrc522_to_card(Transceive_CMD, serial_out, 2, serial_out, &unLen);

    if (status == CARD_FOUND)
    {
        //Check card serial number
        for (i=0; i<4; i++)
        {   
             serNumCheck ^= serial_out[i];
        }
        if (serNumCheck != serial_out[i])
        {   

          status = ERROR;    
        }
    }
    return status;
}
```